# Send Mail by Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

I try to use `Interop.Outlook` to automate Emails sending.

I added the interop.Outlook dll as reference, the `'Embed Interop Types'` property is set to false.

I get 499 errors like:

```
 Cannot embed interop type   
 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._ViewsEvents_ViewRemoveEventHandler'  
 found in both   
 assembly 'project\obj\Debug\Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll'   
 and 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook  
 \14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll'.  
 Consider setting the 'Embed Interop Types' property to false. (CS1758)
```

What is missing?

Comment: from where you find this .dll file?

Comment: @JayeshBhanderi I add a reference to the project, under the `COM` tab I found it. Correct?

Comment: That is right. Why did you set Embed Interop types Property to false?

Comment: @JayeshBhanderi, Thanks, I did not set it, it was set by default. Set it to true doesn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: try by removing .dll file  from Debug folder.

Comment: @JayeshBhanderi, This dll does not exist in the Debug\bin at all.

Comment: check that file in Your project\Obj\Debug directory and if found than delete it.

Comment: @JayeshBhanderi, The same result, I have found it there, deleted and compiled. Nothing changes.

Comment: let me install the outlook on my Computer and than i will give you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will require to check your project setup but still giving a try.

**1**. Do you have this assembly in your bin folder? if yes then remove it and remove reference too from the project.

**2**. Then add the reference again and select the dll from GAC assembly list.

Make sure it does not add dll to your bin dolder this time as it will create problem again.

if above does not work then try following:

1. Goto property page of the project
2. Add reference path there and see if it works.